# Can I trigger an ASP:TextBox Enter keypress event via a button? What is this event exactly?

Tags: asp.net

I'm a little confused here even after doing some research, so hopefully someone can enlighten me.

I have a SqlDataSource, a GridView that uses that SqlDataSource, and a TextBox. While configuring the SqlDataSource, it provides an option to specify a page control that will help run it's query. Here's a picture of exactly what I'm talking about:

[image]
[image]

The control I've specified, "QuerySearchBox", is the Textbox control I mentioned above. When I type something into the box and press Enter, it tailors the SELECT statement, updating the SqlDataSource, which then updates the GridView. This was all set up using the built in wizards, with some minor modification. This is all working totally fine, and as expected.

However, I'd like to provide a button, right next to that TextBox, that triggers the same event that gets called when you press Enter in the TextBox. As in, if you entered text into it and pressed Enter, it would function normally. And, if you pressed the button, the exact same thing would happen, because it would just call the same event.

What is this Enter key event exactly? Is it being handled by the SqlDataSource's configuration settings? Can I mess with it or call it on it's own or change something about it? I haven't been able to find any information that explains how the functionality that the configuration wizard created actually *works*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a text box on a web page, and in place of hitting TAB key, then the enter key will tend to click on (fire) the NEXT button - that button can quite much be anywhere on the page - even inside of a grid). So any link button, or any other button on the page will then be clicked if you hit enter. So, there is no secret event being "automatic" wired up here at all.

So, if you have ANY buttons on that page - even click events for a grid AFTER the text box, then you will trigger a post-back.

So, the text box you have has ZERO specials events, zero speical properties. And there is ZERO hidden code here.

Try hitting tab - you see that nothing happens.

And, since you wired up the text box to DIRECTLY be used as a parmater in the Sqldatasouce on the page?

Then you really don't need any specials event - only a "anything" or more specific ANY button that can or would cause a post back.

In fact, drop in a button right next to your text box - plane jane asp.net button. But do NOT add ANY events or anything to that button. Type text into the box, click on the button, and it will filter for you. (that button - just clicking on it will cause  post-back. Since the text box is connected directly to a parameter, then ANY thing at all on the page causing a post-back will thus filter based on that text box. As a result, you actually don't need any specials code nor events for the filter to work.

In fact, the big downside is with that setup, any post-back will cause a requery of the data to run, and will run based on the parmater you have. In fact, the BIG downside of this design is in fact you have ZERO control of that filter code running. If later on you decide to say add some commbo box, or another button, or ANY control that causes a post-back? Once again, that sql query will ALSO run again.

As you can see, this means you have quite much ZERO control over what button, and when the query + filter will run. (it will run all the time, and every time, and run over and over for anything you do on that page - I would suggest that then this design choice is rather bad, and gives you the developer quite much zero control as to when the filter + query will run.

If you want a search button? Drop in one right beside the text box. you not need ANY code, since ANY post-back will cause the grid to re-load, and re-fire your query, and your query has a parameter that is based on whatever you typed into the text box.

But, try typing in something, and hitting tab - it will move focus to the next control on the page. But, hitting enter? it will CLICK on ANY button control that follows the text box - in fact just about anywhere on the page.

In fact, as a result of above? I tend to not do this, since then you very much get surprises, such as your case.

I in fact don't use Sqldatasources on a page anymore.

What I do, is use the wizard(s) say to build my Gridview. And I don't for example use/have/setup that messy SqlDataSource. And the reason then is you the developer quite much will not have "very" much control of the page.

So, OFTEN use the wizards to load up + setup my GridView.

I then remove the sqldata source, I then remove the DatSource setting in the Gridview markup.

The reason as noted, is often you don't want that parameter, or want it to be optional.

So, say I have a grid and I want to display it - but I also want say a filter.

So, sure - go crazy with wizards. Then as noted, remove SqlDataSource, remove the DataSourceID = "SqldataSoruce1" from the grid view.

So, now I have my markup, say like this:

```
        <div id = "MyGridStuff" runat="server" style="width:50%;padding:25px">

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Search for Fighter" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFigher" runat="server" Style="margin-left:10px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btn"
                style="margin-left:15px"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImage" runat="server" Height="68px" Width="149px"
                           Onclick="btnImage_Click"
                            ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' /> 
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And my code behind is now this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid(Optional strFilter As String = "")

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Fighters ", conn)
            If strFilter <> "" Then
                cmdSQL.CommandText &= " WHERE Fighter LIKE @F + '%' "
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@F", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strFilter
            End If

            cmdSQL.CommandText &= " ORDER BY Fighter"

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData = New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Now, when I run the code, I get this:

[image]

I cannot HUGE LARGE AMAZING, SUPER IMPORANT as to how I check for IsPostBack = false in the page load event. I would say that 99%, or MORE of your web pages will ALWAYS, but ALWAYS check for IsPostBack.

In effect, if IsPostBack = false, then this is the FIRST page load. So like desktop software from VB6, FoxPro, VB.net, ms-access etc? Well, all those systems also have a page load event, but it does not fire EACH TIME.

In other words, any button click, combo box event, or anything? In asp.net web land, that will cause a post-back, and a ALL AND EVERY thing you do on a page with code behind will trigger that post back. and that ALSO means the page load event FIRES every time.

So, the instant I want to control what occures on my page? Then you need that if/then code stub with a test for IsPostBack = false. This becomes your REAL page load event.

So, the above should help what is going on. Since I have my FIRST page load (isPostBack = false) to load up my grid, then each additonal post back (even from the enter key) will not re-load the grid, nor re-filter. It does not re-flter each time, since my GV is not based on a Sqldatasouce in which it will re-load each and every time. and thus ME THE DEVELOPER has to wire up the search button.

In my case, it quite easy to do that, since I desinged the code that way. The code behind my above search button is thus this:

```
Protected Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    LoadGrid(txtFigher.Text)

End Sub
```

So, as pointed out, my page load event ONLY ever fires the first time, and thus that loads up my GV. So, now as a developer, I have 100% control over this operation. It also means I in effect get a "real" page load event like I used to from my VB6, FoxPro, vb.net, ms-access days (my desktop development days).

Now, what about a row click on the GV?

Now, when I click on a grid row Image button (I used a image button to display the picture for each row). If say we click on that image, I would want to display the one picture large on the page. We could do this with 100% client side JavaScript, but lets assume we want to use plane jane vb code behind.

So, in the markup, I will setup a click event for the image button.

We can't just double click on the image button to auto create a click event (becasue the button is INSIDE of the GV). So, we have to go to the markup, and type in OnClick=

As SOON as you hit "=", then inteli-sense will pop up a dialog allowing me to create that click even - it looks like this:

[image]

So, When you hit "=", then you are promoted for a click event. Choose create click event. Looks like nothing occurred. But, Then flip over to code behind, you have a button click (from the grid) to use.

And my code simple hides the "div" that surrounds the GV, and then shows the div below that shows the div with the image control.

So, right below the GV, I have this simple div (a button (back), and a label to display the name of the figher clicked on, and hten a simple image control

This markup:

```
        <div id="imagepop" runat="server" style="display:none;text-align:center;height:80%">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdShowGrid" runat="server" Text="Back" CssClass="btn" />
            <asp:Label ID="fText" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="80%"
            />
        </div>
```

The code behind for that row "image" click looks like this:

```
Protected Sub btnImage_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim btn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer  'gets Grid Row

    ' hide the div that holds the grid
    MyGridStuff.Style.Add("display", "none")

    ' show the div below - with a BIG image control
    imagepop.Style.Add("display", "normal")

    ' set big image to the url from the grid row click
    Image1.ImageUrl = btn.ImageUrl
    fText.Text = gRow.Cells(0).Text

End Sub
```

Keep in mind that EVERY button click still runs the page load event - but our code inside of hte isPostback will ONLY run the first time. this is perhaps the most important aspect of web pages we will ever learn.  I mean, when I click on that row image button, I don't want my sql data source and GV load up code to to run, and as we noted above - it will run EVERY TIME with your current setup. (hence even hitting enter key run that query for the grid. With above design, ONLY when ME the developer wants the code to run will run.

So, when I click on a row, I now get the picture as whole page - like this:

[image]

So, I hope above explains what is going on here - but in most simple terms: Hititng Enterkey or any button on your page will in most cases cause a full page post-back and since your GV is attached to the Sql data source then every page post-back will run-run and re-load the GV each time. And in most cases, you really don't want all that sql to re-run each time, but using the sqldatasource on the page means you the developer give up all control of that GV loading. If you want to start adding buttons, combo boxes, or even my above GV row click event? Then I suggest you dump the sqldata source approach on the page - since it will run each time, every time, and all the time you click on any event on your page - and that means quite much zero control over when and in fact often how the code will run.